# How can login postgres with new created Superuser?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have created a new superuser with

```
sudo su - postgres
createuser --interactive --pwprompt
```

The name is `showkey` and password is `xxxxxx`.

```
postgres=# \du+
                                           List of roles
 Role name  |                         Attributes                         | Member of | Description 
------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------
 dbuser     |                                                            | {}        | 
 debian     |                                                            | {}        | 
 postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}        | 
 showkey    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}        | 
 test_user1 |                                                            | {}        |
```

Now i want to login with `showkey`:

```
psql -U showkey  -W
Password: 
psql: error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "showkey"
```

How can login  postgres with new created Superuser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a line to `pg_hba.conf` *before any other `local` line* that allows the user in:

```
local  all  showkey  md5
```

Then reload PostgreSQL (restart is not necessary).

With the `peer` authentication method, the operating system user has to have the same name as the database user, else authentication will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Do as Laurenz Albe say.

```
sudo  vim  /etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf    
local   all             showkey                                 md5
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

sudo systemctl restart postgresql
psql -d postgres  -U showkey  -W
```